# sequence number generation in db2

Tags: sql, db2, numbers, sequence, db2-400

I have table A which contains 5 columns col1 to col5.totally it contains 6 rows.I am using DB2 sql

Below is the data for col2.

```
A
A
test
testasfdla
Null
Null
```

Requirement:-
If col2 contains null i need assign sequence number starting with 1.

excepted o/p:-

Below is the data for col2.

```
A
A
test
testasfdla
1
2
```

I tried with row_number but did not get the required o/p.

Comment: How did you try with `row_number()` ? How did you order the data if it's important for you ? Do you mean updating the column by assign or a new derived column within the SELECT statement?

Comment: Create a `BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER` that will check `col2` for `null` and use a `SEQUENCE` to assign incrementing numbers if so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
WITH T (C) AS 
(
VALUES
  'A'
, 'A'
, 'test'
, 'testasfdla'
, Null
, Null
)
SELECT COALESCE(C, TO_CHAR(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY C)))
FROM T
```

Comment: Thanks for input and it is working. but if I remove PARTITION BY C clause why I am getting output as 5 and 6 .How db2 will make sure NULLS is assigned last?

Comment: The function with the `partition` clause just enumerates all rows with the same values in `C` independently. You don't need an don't use such an enumeration for non-NULL values with such an expression. So, don't remove this clause, if you don't want to break the functionality needed.

Comment: Add ORDER BY c desc after the partition by C part and you will get 1 and 2 as numbers for the NULLs

Comment: @MichaelTiefenbacher `Order by` the same column as is in the `partition by` clause is useless - it's the same as ordering by a constant. Some database products require the `order by` clause in this function, but not Db2.

Comment: @MarkBarinstein It was a typo when playing with the query. The good running example is at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=13efdae49e81d5cc6b68ca96096165f4).